# Symbolicated iOS crash report from Apple review still not readable

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash-reports, symbolicatecrash

I got a crash report from Apple and symbolicated it following [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html), but I still didn't understand the report.

First, I tried below "XCode approach" to symbolicate the report:

> 1. Connect an iOS device to your Mac
> 2. Choose "Devices" from the "Window" menu
> 3. Under the "DEVICES" section in the left column, choose a device
> 4. Click the "View Device Logs" button under the "Device Information" section on the right hand panel
> 5. Drag your crash report onto the left column of the presented panel
> 6. Xcode will automatically symbolicate the crash report and display the results

Before that, I downloaded dSYM files from App Store by 'Organizer' and copied them into a separated folder. But all the symbolicated names looked like this:

```
5   Recycling                       0x10103b464 fb1UCM8vZCiE + 355
6   Recycling                       0x1010431d4 fbkUVUzGnhkS + 1655
7   Recycling                       0x101038a78 fbIiaWxkoUb6 + 307
```

And then, I tried the approach from [this blog](https://www.avanderlee.com/xcode/symbolicate-crashlogs-xcode-9-bitcode/), but the problem remained:

```
{"app_name":"Recycling","timestamp":"2020-02-08 00:00:51.02 +0800","app_version":"1.7.3","slice_uuid":"20cdeb29-1f14-3298-9649-503635ded968","adam_id":1406292831,"build_version":"3","bundleID":"com.qdjzd.Recycling","share_with_app_devs":true,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 13.3.1 (17D50)","incident_id":"36AEED5C-F4AD-4711-926E-783D4783039E","name":"Recycling"}
Incident Identifier: 36AEED5C-F4AD-4711-926E-783D4783039E
CrashReporter Key:   665569f89a7cca0567f04077cd6e5757ddeffea5
Hardware Model:      xxx1
Process:             Recycling [6029]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0A62AE5B-BE91-4A30-8CB5-A6137DE9DCC1/Recycling.app/Recycling
Identifier:          com.qdjzd.Recycling
Version:             3 (1.7.3)
AppStoreTools:       11C29
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.qdjzd.Recycling [1787]


Date/Time:           2020-02-08 00:00:50.8368 +0800
Launch Time:         2020-02-08 00:00:22.0052 +0800
OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.3.1 (17D50)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    n/a
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  11

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1abab8a48 0x1ab98d000 + 1227336
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1ab7dffa4 0x1ab7da000 + 24484
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1ab9c0e34 0x1ab98d000 + 212532
3   CoreServices                    0x1ac1232d8 0x1ac056000 + 840408
4   Foundation                      0x1abd736f8 0x1abd69000 + 42744
5   Recycling                       0x10103b464 fb1UCM8vZCiE + 355
6   Recycling                       0x1010431d4 fbkUVUzGnhkS + 1655
7   Recycling                       0x101038a78 fbIiaWxkoUb6 + 307
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1ab7d3d8c 0x1ab7c9000 + 44428
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1ab7d776c 0x1ab7c9000 + 59244
```

**Can anyone help me?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone! I finally resolved this problem by myself.

The reason is that I used a 3rd-party library named **UMCCommon** with version **1.5.3**, and all of its symbols are **obfuscated**, so I can not understand.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 10 you can follow these steps:

Inside Organizer, locate the archive where the app is based on.
Click on the Download Debug Symbols button. Nothing will appear in your Downloads folder, but that's OK.
Connect the build machine to an iOS device.
Select the device in Devices and Simulators.
Click on the View Devices Logs button.
Drag-and-drop the crash file to the left panel. The file must end with a .crash extension, otherwise the drag fails.
Switch to the All Logs tab.
Select the added crash file.
The file should automatically symbolicate, otherwise use the right-click context menu item Re-Symbolicate Log.

Comment: Thanks for your replying! That's what I tried more than 5 times, but the memory addresses are still unreadable, just the 0x...s changed to fb...s.